# Unexpected state - JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode

Tags: json.net

I have this json -

```
[{"a":"2958081","b":"Contact Sport","e":"abc4 news sport recent","f":[{"a":"831081","f":"2011-09-30 23:00:00","g":"2011-10-14 23:00:00"},{"a":"831080","f":"2011-09-23 23:00:00","g":"2011-10-07 23:00:00"}]},{"a":"2959838","b":"ABC National Evening News","e":"news abc4 recent last-chance","f":[{"a":"831928","f":"2011-09-30 23:00:00","g":"2011-10-01 22:00:00"}]}]
```

which gives me an exception

> "Unexpected state: Finished. Line 1, position 206."

with the following code:

```
doc = CType(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "root"), XmlDocument)
```

`json` is `string`, `doc` is `XmlDocument`

Is there a way to handle these repeated array structures? I have shown 2 only, the full JSON file (string) has ~250 (total 75K bytes). The [ ] enclosing the  whole is stripped out before the code snippet shown.

Answer (score 0):

One solution was provided by @VoidMain at the [CodePlex JSON.NET discussion](http://json.codeplex.com/discussions/275313).

It requires minor edit of the string, pre-pending {object: and appending } to the json as written above.

```
{objects:[{"a":"2958081","b":"Contact Sport","e":"abc4 news sport recent","f":[{"a":"831081","f":"2011-09-30 23:00:00","g":"2011-10-14 23:00:00"},{"a":"831080","f":"2011-09-23 23:00:00","g":"2011-10-07 23:00:00"}]},{"a":"2959838","b":"ABC National Evening News","e":"news abc4 recent last-chance","f":[{"a":"831928","f":"2011-09-30 23:00:00","g":"2011-10-01 22:00:00"}]}]}
```